# Can someone please help me find this book with a black tree?

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading a book, but I can't remember by who or the title. I know there was a like some sort of black tree that gave death or life maybe. And there were these certain people that lived high in these mountains and got sunlight? The main character was a kid and he had some sort of bodyguard from his dad maybe. They took a plane somewhere I think in one book of the series, and the plane crashed. Sorry I don't remember much. I read the series around two years ago.

Comment: What do you mean 'got sunlight'? As in they collected it, or just were nearer to it? In the Sunstone Scrolls series by Sydney Van Scyoc, women called baronhas collected the sun in special bracelets. The rest doesn't match though.

Comment: This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)